# Actions on idle account holders

Tags: support, user-accounts, activity

I have a question regarding active account holders.

Consider an account that logs in everyday, but doesn't participate in anything on Meta Stack Overflow. Is there any action taken on such accounts?

Or is there any system that will monitor such accounts and remove them from the system?

Comment: Why *should* there be any action taken? I don't see a reason.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, on several fora and communities, inactive accounts are removed, so it isn't a bad/strange question.

Comment: @Gamecat: I'm not saying it's a bad question. I just don't know what the reasoning behind such a feature would be. And "other communities do it" is not in itself a reason. **Why** do they do that? *What* is the *problem* with having idle accounts? I'm not asking to be complicated, but out of curiosity.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer : we are holding accounts who are abscand and not participating anymore . so such accounts can trun to inactive, even sometimes delete from the system?

Comment: @Damodar: I understand that they *can* or *could* be turned inactive, but **why should they**? What advantage does the system/community gain from doing so? What disadvantage does it suffer from not doing so? What problem does it solve?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer : but i dnt feel any use in holding such members in application, except showing we have such big count of members

Comment: One big advantage is that idle members can chose to participate at any one time, if they ever chose to. They don't need to go to any "re-activation" or "re-registration", they can just start participating if they want. That's a *big* plus in my opinion. I still don't see a single advantage of getting rid of those accounts.

Comment: @Damodar: Do you have any other reason for *deleting users* than "I don't like it"? IIRC, there's no member count displayed anywhere on the site - as it's irrelevant (as opposed to *question* count). On the other hand, coming back to a site after a period of inactivity  to find your account deleted - that is a pretty big negative impact in my opinion. Are you suggesting that the site *decrease* its usefulness to appease your sense of cleanliness? There are bigger fish to fry in this regard (e.g. duplicate questions, low-quality etc), and those actually have a negative impact if left unchecked.

Comment: @Piskvor's Semifinite Monkeys : closing the duplicate question and low quality questions etc ,made any negative impact? In the same way if we make its part of rules in SO as "inactive accounts will be deleted after certain period of time " will not make any negative impact.

Comment: @Damodar: it **definitely** has a negative impact for any user who's account gets deleted and then comes back, trying to participate. You've yet to demonstrate a single **positive impact** that it would make.

Comment: @Damodar: Quite the opposite: dealing with duplicates et al prevents the site from becoming a digital landfill, thus *preventing* negative impacts. With users, this is not necessary - and keeping a user in the db is actually positive: I can go and see that the user last visited the site 1 day ago, 1 week ago, 1 month ago, or 1 year ago - which gives me a hint how likely xe's likely to be active *now*. Note also that we've had users take a several-months-long break from SO, *and then come back*. If your suggestion were implemented, I doubt they would bother.

Comment: Since no argument **for** deleting users has been given except "if others jump off a bridge, so should we" and "I don't *like* this", I see no point in this discussion. Piskvor over and out.

Comment: @Piskvor: so it was you after all! I was fooled and thought it was your monkeys!

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: We sort of [represent him](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19746/piskvors-semifinite-monkeys) here on Meta.

Answer (score 5):

No, if you don't participate, your account stays alive.

Of course you won't get much out of that account.

Note that you must get at least 200 rep to get the yearling badge.